# knockout.js Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I am using Porto v2.2.0 – Ultimate Responsive Magento Theme and showing error like

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
Message: cart is not a function
```

Comment: Share your model, seems like `cart` is not an `ko.observable`, function or `computed` field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved it in three steps:

1. Replace the **minicart.phtml** file from theme (app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t) with core template (vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​).
2. Replace **content.html** file from your theme (app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html) with core template (vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html)
3. Remove all pub/static/frontend , remove var folder. 
   Run deploy static content again : **php magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Result minicart after fixed :

[image]

Comment: Anyone help me regard diff between php magento setup:static-content:deploy vs php magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: In default and developer mode Magento generates static content on demand. But if you want force static content deploy you need to use -f parameter.